# New order email not being sent to the seller

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

The problem is, when a customer places an order on my store, they receive the confirmation email, but the new order email, is never sent to the seller

- Other emails such as product out of stock and contact form are being sent without problem

I'm on ps 1.7.7. The mail alerts module is on the latest version 2.4.0. PHP version on the server is 7.1

I've tried reinstalling the mail alerts module but nothing changed. When I send the test email, it is sent without problem

Comment: Welcome! FYI this is off-topic here, as it's not a programming question. Seems more of a product support question, and probably best to reach out directly to the appropriate support channel.

Answer (score 0):

another one here with the same problem, but with the prestashop version 1.7.8.8... I have already verified that the email files in my language are created in the michildtemplate/modules/ps_emailalerts/es or en/ directory but still without function...

@xandraco If you want to fix it temporarily while they look for the problem (already reported to the github-prestashop community) reinstall the module version 2.3.3 and it will work for you.